# How to publish an updated version of connector in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm a developer and I've created an updated version of an existing connector of our service in Power BI. How do I publish the new version in Power BI and get rid of the old one? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check this might be helpful https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2018/04/23/refreshing-a-power-bi-custom-connector-in-the-cloud/

Comment: My issue is not regarding refreshing data in Power BI Cloud. Its actually how to provide a version update for the existing published connector.

Comment: Above link i pasted does same of what your requirement. Have you red fully?